# How can I delete an model entry at a given time (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create the functionality in my app where a given entry in the database is set to delete at a certain time.  I am new to rails an I am unsure how I can achieve this.

For example, once the expired time of an entry has been passed I want it to be deleted automatically.  Any hints or ideas how this can be achieved? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a rake task periodically (like every hour or every night). This job will check posts and delete expired ones.

You can schedule rake tasks using [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever/) gem, for example.

```
every 3.hours do
  rake "jobs:clear_stale"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Background job is what will solve your problem. `Resque` and `Sidekiq` are two awesome options on background job. You can keep scheduler that runs in specific interval to check if entry has expired and if yes, delete the entry. [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque) is the railcasts on resque and [this one]. Whenever is also an option but the other two mentioned above are still better.